# PHP Preg_replace of String

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a String like this "{\i1}You were happy?{\i0}"
and I want to remove all "{...}" that just the Text "You were happy?" is left.

I have tried it with some regex pattern but i did not get it work.

One of my try:

```
text = preg_replace("/{.*}/", "\\0", $text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this for replacing all the text between `{}`

`$result = preg_replace('/\{[^}]*\}/', '', $subject);`

**Explanation**

```
"
\{      # Match the character “{” literally
[^}]    # Match any character that is NOT a “}”
   *       # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\}      # Match the character “}” literally
"
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should make the matches ungreedy. Apply a `?` after `*`.

The opening `{` does not need to be escaped in this very example, but I'd do it anyway.

And then you are using `\0` as replacement pattern. That will *reinsert* whatever the regex matched. So nothing would be removed in the end - which I heard is not what you want.

```
 $text = preg_replace("/\{.*?}/", "", $text);
```